# How to hide injected dependencies from template member function factory

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, factory-pattern

I have a C++ project which is divided into subproject.  One of the projects has a factory implemented with a template member function that injects dependencies, similar to this:

```cpp
class FooManager {
public:

    // stuff

    template<class TBar>
    TBar makeInstance() {
        return TBar(depA, depB);
    }

private:
    DependencyA depA;
    DependencyB depB;
};
```

Now, the problem is that this forces `DependencyA` and `DependencyB` to be a part of the interface of `FooManager`.

Is there any way to have a template member function to work as a factory method but in a way that it hides the injected types from the interface?

edit: hiding `depA` and `depB` in a pimpl is an option on the table, so is explicit template specialization for all `TBar` types.

Comment: Not, unless you want to restrict yourself to a limited set of template parameters for the member function. In order for the compiler to specialize `makeInstance`, it needs to know about the types of `depA` and `depB`. How else would it do overload resolution for the constructor of whatever you pass? Alternatively you could of course make `makeInstance` only a declaration in the header, mention the specializations but define the specializations in a cpp file and use the pimpl ideom, but this restricts you to a limited set of specializations for the member function...

Comment: If you're just trying to have forward declarations for `DependencyA` and `DependencyB` you could of course use pimpl + 2 functions returning references to the dependencies that are implemented in a `.cpp` file. But this is at the cost of having to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: That's not a factory method as far as the GoF definition goes. If you do make it a classic GoF-compliant factory method, the problem magically solves itself.

Comment: You could use the PIMPL method, but I reckon trying to hide all implementation details isn't a strategy that works well in the long-run.

Comment: Using a pimpl is an option on the table, as is passing explicit template specialization for all `TBar` types.  What I'd like to have is a way to not have to repeat the same boilerplate factory code for each a factory for each `TBar` type, and still hide dependencies from the interface.